# Difference between Ordinary Least Squares and R square (Coefficient of determination)?

Tags: statistics, data-science

*Hi,

Could someone point out the difference between -  Ordinary Least Squares and R square (Coefficient of determination)? 
They seem pretty much similar to me both are calculating the difference between estimated and actual value, summing and then square them. Maybe I have got it wrong. Any advise ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinary Least Squares is a regression method, and R-squared is a metric that represents how much a dependent variable is explained by an independent variable or variables in a regression model.

For example, if you correlate GDP per Capita (your dependent variable) with Industrialization level (independent variable) of a list of countries and your regression gives you a R-squared of 0.89, it means that industrialization explains 89% of GDP per Capita.

> The most general definition of the coefficient of determination is
>
> **R-squared = 1 - (SSRes / SSTot), where:**
>
> SSRes is the regression sum of squares, also called the explained sum
>   of squares
>
> SSTot is total sum of squares

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination

An OLS regression involves matrices algebra and it's a bit more complicated for me to demonstrate here (altough I'm not an expert on it). Please check for reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Matrix/vector_formulation

The important thing here is to you understand that OLS and R-squared are two different things. You do a regression to correlate one dependent variable to many independent variables and use the R-squared to see if this regression makes sense.

Comment: could you point out what is the difference in how the two are being calculated ?

Comment: I made some changes in my answer

Answer (score -1):

OLS regression will be discussed in the context of a bivariate model, that is, a model in which there is only one independent variable ( X ) predicting a dependent variable ( Y ).

Where as the R^2 square will be used to evaluate the variance explained by the model we Built.

Comment: OLS can be used with multivariate as well.